# Wordpress Rest API - Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a custom post type in Wordpress and exposed it to rest API. I have also added custom fields to this post using the ACF plugin.

In my themes function.php I have registered these fields in the response and I can see them when I make a get request.

`register_rest_field('auto', 'specs', array('get_callback' => 'get_autos_specs_for_api'));`

The problem is that when I send a post request, wordpress doesn't recognize these fields. It creates a new post with the title and all the extra fields are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try that solution:

```
function wp_api_encode_acf($data,$post,$context){
    $data['meta'] = array_merge($data['meta'],get_fields($post['ID']));
    return $data;
}

if( function_exists('get_fields') ){
    add_filter('json_prepare_post', 'wp_api_encode_acf', 10, 3);
}
```

Refer: https://gist.github.com/rileypaulsen/9b4505cdd0ac88d5ef51

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing I saw. I think that is for the plugin. It doesn't work with the built in wordpress API.

Comment: I understand, Why do not you try to use the default WP function to get a meta `get_post_meta` ?

Answer (score 0):

For me what did the trick was to hook yourself to the rest prepare post and then add your fields to the array, then return the response object.

```
function slug_add_data($response, $post) {

    $response->data['latitud'] = get_field('latitud', $response->data['id']);
    $response->data['longitud'] = get_field('longitud', $response->data['id']);

    return $response;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'slug_add_data', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the custom code, Use the out of the box solution for accessing ACF fields into the Rest API.
Plugin URL: https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api

Add the filter as below:

```
//Filter to to get acf field within acf field for relational field set
add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/<custom_posttype>/get_fields', function( $data ) {
    if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
        array_walk_recursive( $data, 'get_fields_recursive' );
    }

    return $data;
} );
```

You will get the ACF fields object inside the default WordPress Rest API response it's self, If all configuration are correct.

Let me know if any helps needed!